# But some files are not read in vscode.(model_mobilefacenet,photo2cartoon_weights.pt) When I try to open it I get the message

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX3hh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLE1s.png)

But some files are not read in vscode.(model_mobilefacenet,photo2cartoon_weights.pt) When I try to open it I get the message (the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding) if i click (open anyway)

How yo fix it! this issue